# Black screen with just a mouse pointer after boot, Kali linux (impossible to get a shell)

Tags: kali-linux, kde, grub

I have let my laptop with kali linux, but there is a power cut and before i have been remove the battery of my laptop after a problem, and when i want to access to my kali linux i can't, my pc boot normally, i have the grub menu but after a black screen with my mouse pointer and it's all, in recovery mode it's the same...

can you help me please.

my screen:
[image: the screen of my laptop]

PS: i can access to the tty

EDIT: in tty i have try to relaunch kde (my environment for kali) and when i want to get my kde version i get this error :

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, unc, wayland-egl, way land, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
```

image:
[image: photo of the error of kde]

Comment: Can you access tty?

Comment: Yes, i can access to tty

Comment: Did you by chance reset your BIOS settings? it could have happened even after having no power. Maybe something changed, graphics settings, etc. What happens when your restart your desktop environment from tty?

Comment: Exactly the same issue here. This is why linux will never be a mainstream desktop OS. There’s a 99% chance you’ll end up stuck and need to open a terminal and type commands to fix something, which 99% of computer users aren’t comfortable doing.